# Chrome developer tools network blocking. Fix from server side

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome-devtools

I a PHP script that takes about 10 seconds to complete. When I run the request in Chrome in two different tabs, the second request waits for the first request to finish and only than it starts.

When I look in the Timing in chrome I see that Blocking takes 10 second for the second request.
Is there any configuration I can do on the server side to prevent that?

I am using XAMPP with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5 
Everything is done on my localhost

Here is my phpinfo as PDF:
[phpinfo.pdf](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mystackoverflow/phpinfo.pdf)

Another thing I have noticed is that it only happens when I am using the exact URL in two different tabs. Event If I use different URL parameters it execute the script simultaneously

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using sessions?

Comment: No. I set session.use_cookies=0 in php.ini. I have added a link to my phpinfo. Maybe I am missing someing

Comment: Are you using any other shared resources, like an open file handle?

Comment: Could it be http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients ?

Comment: Yes Redis. But would not it count as "waiting" if that was the problem?

Comment: Don't think its MaxClients problem. This is my configuration: <IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   50
</IfModule>

Comment: My guess is that this is due to HTTP pipelining, or Apache trying to be smart when optimizing. At this moment, I don't have exact "what to do" type of comment, but you should try and google how to disable it.

Comment: I will check that. I have also seen that if I change URL or adds Parameters it does work simultaneously. This question seems related and says it related to the browser cache entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189591/multiple-ajax-requests-for-same-url