# Cakephp : Multiple Async Ajax calls not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, asynchronous

I have two consecutive Async Ajax calls as below, when I execute that, I am expecting '1st complete' will be print if it takes less time than call2 (id=2) vice-versa '2nd complete' will be print if it takes less time than call1 (id=1).
But, I observe that second call always wait for first call to complete. get confuse with Async. please help.

```
    $(function(){
       jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: 'Home/getItem', 
            data : { id : 1 }, 
            async:true,
            success: function(){ console.log('1st complete'); }
        }),
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: 'Home/getItem', 
            data : { id : 2 }, 
            async:true,
            success: function(){ console.log('2nd complete'); }
        })
});
```

When I check same functions with core php, it return expected results.

Comment: @Alex you seem to have misunderstanding of `async:true`

Comment: maybe this has something to do with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189591/multiple-ajax-requests-for-same-url

Comment: also worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060539/parallel-asynchronous-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Comment: @alex, no both request start at same time but response get in order..

Comment: which technology you are using at backend? is it a .Net?

Comment: @bhups but what is your expected behavior? and how are you sure it "waits" until the first call is done? which browser are you using?

Comment: @Alex, I confirmed with results when execute single call at a time, call1 takes nearly 3sec and call2 takes nearly 600ms. as call2 take less time I want call2 will be response first and then call1. and I am using chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing such output because; almost in each server side technology there is a session management. Now assume that your `getItem` function/method do some job and update the session object. So by default server always prevent `concurrent` call to same server side method by same user. If first request is going on then second request gets pushed onto the queue. And once first request gets completed; the pending request gets executed. By this way `session state` modified by first request will get available to 2nd request and so on.

In .Net technology there are annotation to make controller/methods session unaware so that concurrent ajax calls can be made. Via these annotations we declare that the related controller/method doesn't deal with session state and hence OK to call concurrently.

You can read more about it in below SO question:

[Why would multiple simultaneous AJAX calls to the same ASP.NET MVC action cause the browser to block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428413/why-would-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-calls-to-the-same-asp-net-mvc-action-cause)

Similarly there has to be something in PHP. Try searching it and you will get the clue.