# why is fasthttp like single process?

Tags: go, fasthttp

```
requestHandler := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

    time.Sleep(time.Second*time.Duration(10))
    fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Hello, world! Requested path is %q", ctx.Path())
}


s := &fasthttp.Server{
Handler: requestHandler
}

if err := s.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:82"); err != nil {
log.Fatalf("error in ListenAndServe: %s", err)
}
```

multiple request,and it cost time like  X*10s.
fasthttp is single process?

**after two days...**
I am sorry for this question,i describe my question not well.My question is caused by the browser，the browser request the same url by synchronization, and it mislead me, it make think the fasthttp web server hanlde the request by synchronization.

Comment: How did you issue the multiple requests in client? Please provide the client codes.

Comment: I just use Browser,open more than one "http://127.0.0.1:82", and the last opened ,it cost X*10 second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think instead of *fasthttp is single process?*, you're asking whether fasthttp handles client requests concurrently or not?

I'm pretty sure that any server (including *fasthttp*) package will handle client requests concurrently. You should write a test/benchmark instead of manually access the server through *several* browsers. The following is an example of such test code:

```
package main_test

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func doRequest(uri string) error {
    resp, err := http.Get(uri)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func TestGet(t *testing.T) {
    N := 1000
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(N)

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        go func() {
            if err := doRequest("http://127.0.0.1:82"); err != nil {
                t.Error(err)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()

    t.Logf("Total duration for %d concurrent request(s) is %v", N, time.Since(start))
}
```

And the result (in my computer) is

> fasthttp_test.go:42: Total duration for 1000 concurrent request(s) is 10.6066411s

You can see that the answer to your question is **No, it handles the request concurrently**.

**UPDATE:**

In case the requested URL is the same, your browser may perform the request sequentially. See [Multiple Ajax requests for same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189591/multiple-ajax-requests-for-same-url). This explains why the response times are `X*10s`.

Comment: My english is very poor.Thanks very much.
You answer is very correct。And make me know the why.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for this question,i  describe my question not well.My question is caused by the browser，the browser request the same url by synchronization, and it mislead me, it make think the fasthttp web server hanlde the request by synchronization.